# pass argument to installer via bash

Tags: linux, bash, apt-get

I'm trying to do an unattended install of phpmyadmin however during the install it prompts you to select which web server your using ie apache or lighttpd what i'd like to do is pass the lighttpd value automatically ie

```
apt-get install phpmyadmin &value lighttpd
```

Comment: Personally I'd file a bug against the package. Installation should **never require** user input. It should always have a default value and a way to reconfigure that later.

Answer (score 4):

You can use echo with pipe:

```
echo "lightttpd" | apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

From [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/524018)

Comment: thank you just checked and now it's asking 2 questions so can i do     echo "no" | echo "lighttpd" | echo apt-get install phpmyadmin

Comment: You code doesn't appear to work as the prompt doesn't require 'lighttpd' to be typed in but rather selected.

Answer (score 2):

I installed phpmyadmin

```
apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

Then used conf-selections to return the values

```
sudo debconf-get-selections | grep phpmyadmin | grep lighttpd
```

Which returned

```
phpmyadmin      phpmyadmin/reconfigure-webserver        multiselect     lighttpd
```

So in my script I had

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/reconfigure-webserver multiselect lighttpd" | debconf-set-selections
apt-get install -y phpmyadmin
```

Ran it and it no longer prompted for that value.